# Selecting the same item from a set without knowing the set's size

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I don't know if this is possible or not but I thought I'd ask.

Given an ordered list a1,...,an

Is it possible that if each element of the list represented numeric indexes that I could consistently map some input value to the same index without knowing the size of the set?

For e.g. the algorithm here http://bayesianthink.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/the-random-picker-algorithm.html?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=t.co

describes a process for randomly picking an item from a list.

I think I've phrased it the best I can but if it is unclear what I'm asking I can add more info/background or migrate to StackOverlow where I could explain a bit better with code.

**Edit :** removed use of "set", I mean an ordered list/sequence so 1,2,3...n

Comment: A set does not recognize order of its elements, they are all on the same footing so to speak. A list however is assumed to order the elements. I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I do not understand that algorithm in the link either. It says choose the person $i$ with probability $1/i$. Doesn't this mean the first person is chosen at all times?

Comment: @Maesumi Yes, you always (tentatively) select the first person. But you replace it with probability $\frac12$ with the second person. Then you replace whomever you currently have with the third person with probability $\frac13$ and so on. This standard procedure is known as random sampling. -  But I have no idea what the OP wants.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: Use the "same input" as seed for a random generator and perfrom the random sampling as described?